# 18.04.1 LTS infinite boot time

Tags: server, virtualization, input-devices, hyper-v, boot-time

Our Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS is no longer booting up.
Here is what's happening.
(please forgive the screenshot but I can't copy'n'paste...
[image: Screenshot from Hyper-V Manager]

Any idea on what is going on?

EDIT1:

- This is a virtual machine hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2.
- This VM has been stable for years.
- Upgrades have been made from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04LTS and then 18.04 LTS in the past year.

## EDIT2:

#### Seems it was a kernel issue. Changing kernel version fixed the problem for good. Bringing back the faulty kernel brought back the problem...

Comment: The virtual keyboard is getting disconnected and reconnected. Why that is, I'm not sure. Try to log in and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Unfortunately, can't log in, since it never ends booting up... Much appreciated anyway, will help to search in that direction.

Comment: It's already booted up and at the login prompt, in your screenshot. Just type your username and password.

Comment: Problem caused by the upgrade of linux-firmware to 1.173.3. And no, the boot sequence has not ended yet, and can't log in at all, can't even type anything... ty

Comment: Did you ever fix this? experiencing the exact same problem.

Comment: Yes, at work though, I’ll give you more hints as soon as I can connect later today.